# How to do a batch upsert from a list of document references?

Tags: mongodb

I'm doing large updates using an `$in` query. They look something like this:

```
collection.update(
    { "ref": { "$in": [<list of ObjectIds>] } }, 
    { "$set": { "foo": "bar" } }, 
    { "multi" : true, "upsert" : false } 
);
```

This updates any document linked by the `ref` field and sets the `foo` field to "bar".

The trouble is that I also want **upsert** behaviour, such that any **missing** documents (not already linked by reference) get inserted and linked in the process.

I can achieve this with various long-winded approaches using iteration, but
I'm asking if there's a good, succinct and performant way to do it using Mongo operators.

I am running Mongo 2.6 so can't yet use any 3.x features.

**Update for clarity:**

To give an example of the desired result. Suppose a collection is completely empty and I have two references from another collection:

```
var refs = [ ObjectId(a), ObjectId(b) ];
```

I want the upsert to populate two new documents, so the collection will then contain:

```
[ { "_id": ObjectId(x),
    "ref": ObjectId(a), // <- first ref from $in list
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  { "_id": ObjectId(y),
    "ref": ObjectId(b), // <- second ref from $in list
    "foo": "bar"
  } ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the option `"multiple":true` is not a valid MongoDB option for `.update()` - it is `multi:true` instead. For further clarification please have a look at the [update() documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter).

As for your question I personally think that the [Bulk Operation Methods](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/js-bulk/) introduced in 2.6 could be the easiest way to achieve what you want:

You have an array with the following elements

```
x = [1,2,3,4,6]
```

then you define a bulk variable

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
```

after this you loop through your elements in `x[]` in order to [Bulk.find()](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/Bulk.find/) and apply an [Bulk.find.update()](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/) with [Bulk.find.upsert()](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/)

```
for ( i=0; i < x.length; i++)
{
    bulk.find({"ref":x[i]}).upsert().update({$setOnInsert:{"ref":x[i]},$set:{"foo":"bar"}});
}
```

finally you [Bulk.execute()](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/Bulk.execute/) the bulk

```
bulk.execute()
```

The above update() command will then either [$set](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/update/set/) the value of "foo" to "bar" if it matches the query on "ref" or insert a document if it does not match. [$setOnInsert](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) is responsible for the creation of the "ref" value in your inserted document as it only sets when a document gets inserted.

One advantage of [Bulk Operation Methods](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/js-bulk/) is also the fact it reports back on what has been inserted, upserted and updated:

```
BulkWriteResult({
    "writeErrors" : [ ],
    "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 5,
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "nRemoved" : 0,
    "upserted" : [
        {
            "index" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("56f0de3d8187bc0dc8faa46b")
        },
        {
            "index" : 1,
            "_id" : ObjectId("56f0de3d8187bc0dc8faa46c")
        },
        {
            "index" : 2,
            "_id" : ObjectId("56f0de3d8187bc0dc8faa46d")
        },
        {
            "index" : 3,
            "_id" : ObjectId("56f0de3d8187bc0dc8faa46e")
        },
        {
            "index" : 4,
            "_id" : ObjectId("56f0de3d8187bc0dc8faa46f")
        }
    ]
})
```

The commands and methods above have been tested in MongoDB v2.6.5